# HTML tags inside paragraph <p>

Tags: html

I'm working on a small "shoe size" project, where the user should be able to read an article about a special shoe. The reader can on a button choose either to get the EU or US sizes inside the article.

My question is, how can i do this the best way - since i actually don't wan't to create a new `<p>` tag inside a `<p>` tag..

```
<p>This is the start of the article and this shoe is only available in <p units="US">11.5</p> <p units="EU">45</p></p>.
```

Comment: could use `<div>`s. Why do you explicitly not want to create a new `<p>` tag?

Comment: Your HTML is malformed, a `<p>` element can't be nested inside another `<p>` element; the inner elements could be replaced by other elements such as `<span>`, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var units = $('#changeUnit');
var unitUS = $('#US');
var unitEU = $('#EU');

function changeUnit() {
 if (unitUS.css('display') == 'inline') {
  unitUS.css('display', 'none');
  unitEU.css('display', 'inline'); 
  units.text('EU size (click to change)');
 } else {
  unitUS.css('display', 'inline');
  unitEU.css('display', 'none'); 
  units.text('US size (click to change)');
 }
}

units.click(function(e) {
    changeUnit();
});
```

```css
#US {
  display: inline;
  }
#EU {
  display: none;
  }
 #changeUnit {
 cursor: pointer;  
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="changeUnit">US size (click to change)</p>

<p>This is the start of the article and this shoe is only available in <span id="US" units="US">11.5</span><span id="EU" units="EU">45</span>.</p>
```

Answer (score 5):

To cover the primary issues, relating to the validity of your HTML or, specifically, the *in*validity of your HTML:

1. a `<p>` element cannot contain another block element, it can only contain, "phrasing content," and its:

> end tag may be omitted if the `p` element is immediately followed by an `address`, `article`, `aside`, `blockquote`, `div`, `dl`, `fieldset`, `footer`, `form`, `h1`, `h2`, `h3`, `h4`, `h5`, `h6`, `header`, `hgroup`, `hr`, `main`, `nav`, `ol`, `p`, `pre`, `section`, `table`, or `ul`, element…

Therefore if the browser encounters a nested `<p>` that nested `<p>` is immediately interpreted as a sibling of the currently-open `<p>` element (the extraneous end-tags are merely discarded as erroneous mark-up). Because the content of these nested elements aren't – syntactically or semantically – a *paragraph* I converted them to `<span>` elements, which are 'neutral' containers (they imply nothing of the contents), which can be contained within a `<p>` element and contain phrasing content.

2. The `units` attribute is a non-standard, custom, user-created attribute and therefore invalid; however user-defined attributes are allowed *if* they're preceded with the `data-` prefix; so to make your attributes valid I merely converted them from `units` to `data-units`.

That said, this is the resulting HTML (of that part), note that I also moved the sentence-closing period within the paragraph, for syntactic correctness:

```
<p>This is the start of the article and this shoe is only available in
  <span data-units="US">11.5</span>
  <span data-units="EU">45</span>.</p>
```

Now, your question was how to use a button to show/hide the sizing information, to show either the US sizing, or the EU sizing; to do that is easier with JavaScript, but there is a (slightly messy) hack available to allow native HTML and CSS to implement that behaviour using `<label>` and `<input>` elements.

The `<label>` element is linked to an `<input>` element of `type="radio"`, and the relevant radio-inputs share the same name, so that only one can be selected at a time.

These radio-inputs precede the `<p>` element(s) within which the sizing information is held that you want to toggle, and CSS is used to select the checked radio-input and then show only the specific content, hiding the other.

In practice this gives:

```css
label {
  /* irrelevant, and merely for aesthetics: */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 3em;
  height: 2em;
  background-color: #999;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 900;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  padding: 0.25em;
}
/* the :checked pseudo-class allows us to select
   the selected/'checked' input, and the adjacent
   sibling combinator ('+') traverses from the
   checked input to the adjacent label element: */

input:checked + label {
  background-color: limegreen;
}
/* visually moving the inputs of 'type=radio' (using
   a CSS attribute-selector) off the page, so it's
   not visible to the user; choose any suitably large
   value according to your preference: */

input[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  left: -10000px;
}
/* hiding all span elements with a 'data-units'
   attribute: */

span[data-units] {
  display: none;
}
/* if the element with the id of 'us' is checked
   we traverse to the later paragraph siblings
   (using the general-sibling combinator ('~')
   and from those paragraphs we find the descendant
   span elements with a data-unit attribute-value of
   'US' and display them as 'inline-block': */

#us:checked ~ p span[data-units=US] {
  display: inline-block;
}
/* as above, but we use the id of 'eu' to ultimately
   find the spans with the data-attribute of 'EU': */

#eu:checked ~ p span[data-units=EU] {
  display: inline-block;
}
/* this selects the spans with the data-units attribute
   and creates some generated content to show the sizing
   (in case the selected sizing is off-screen, perhaps;
   here we generate the string of ' (US)' or ' (EU)'
   although the US and EU can be replaced by whatever is held
   in the data-units attribute: */

span[data-units]::after {
  content: ' (' attr(data-units)')';
  color: #999;
  font-size: smaller;
}
```

```html
<!-- the input here precedes the associated label (note the shared
     id of the input and the 'for' of the label) in order to allow
     the label to have a 'selected' state; the inputs also precede
     the paragraph containing the elements to toggle, in order for
     the CSS cascade to work -->
<input id="us" type="radio" name="sizing" checked />
<label for="us">US</label>
<input id="eu" type="radio" name="sizing" />
<label for="eu">EU</label>

<p>This is the start of the article and this shoe is only available in <span data-units="US">11.5</span>  <span data-units="EU">45</span>.</p>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/718oqs1r/).

References:

- HTML Specifications:

  - [Paragraph (`<p>`) element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element).
  - [Phrasing content](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#phrasing-content-1).
  - [Span (`<span>`) element](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-span-element).
- CSS:

  - [Adjacent-sibling (`+`) combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators).
  - [Attribute-selectors](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-selectors).
  - [`:checked` pseudo-class](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#checked).
  - [General-sibling (`~`) combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#general-sibling-combinators).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i'm questioning if this is the right answer in my case. What i want to do is to be able to read from a HTML parser, and get both <span data-units>. I'm not sure if this is possible with <span>..

Comment: Then you probably should have described your problem in your question, because *that* problem and the question you asked seem quite different. But while this may not be the answer you need, I don't understand why an HTML parser couldn't parse `<span>` tags.

Answer (score 3):

Conventionally, the phrasing element

```
<span>
```

is used to isolate inline text within a paragraph.

**Eg.**

```
<p>
This is the start of the article and this shoe is only available in
<span data-units="US">11.5</span>
<span data-units="EU">45</span>
.</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i'm questioning if this is the right answer in my case. What i want to do is to be able to read from a HTML parser, and get both <span data-units>. I'm not sure if this is possible with <span>