# How to style a child component of a tag inside a v-html

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, sass

I'm trying to style an img tag inside a p tag on a v-html in vuejs, i can style the p tag directly but selecting the img tag is a bit hard because `p ~ img` and `p + img` won't work is there a way around this. The content of the v-html is coming from the wp-rest api

v-html content

```
<p><img class="aligncenter" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1488590528505-98d2b5aba04b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&amp;ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&amp;w=1000&amp;q=80" alt="turned on gray laptop computer"></p>
```

SinglePost.vue

```
<div class="works__content_grid">
  <p class="works__content" v-html="work.post.content.rendered"></p>

</div>
```

```
<style lang='sass' scoped>
.works
 &__content
  p
  img
   width: 100px
</style>
```

Comment: You cannot nest paragraphs, that is, a paragraph element cannot have `<p>` descendants. If it were possible, why not use a descendant selector `p img { ... }`?

Comment: @connexo i tried changing it to a div tag and still wont work

Comment: A `<p>` also cannot contain a `<div>`.

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/35254308/3744304

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem why it is not styling your image is tag `scoped`

When using tag `scoped` Vue JS will generate a hash for your component and styling to make CSS scoped.

However, you generated content `v-html="work.post.content.rendered"` is not there in the moment when assigning hashes, therefore, styles are not applied

To solve this you have to either
 1. Remove `scoped` 
 2. Use /deep/ tag in SASS:

```
<style lang="sass" scoped>
.works
&__content
 /deep/ p,
 /deep/ img
   width: 100px
</style>
```

I find useful doc [here](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors)

Answer (score 2):

A [paragraph is a very special HTML Element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) that comes with some restrictions:

- you cannot nest `p` elements
- `p` elements cannot contain alot of elements, such as e.g. `div` (only [phrasing content](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#phrasing-content-2) is allowed)

When the browser, in your "outer" `p` finds another `p` or `div`, here's what it does:

Your HTML:

```
<p>foo
   <p>bar</p>
</p>
```

What the browser corrects that to:

```
<p>foo</p>
<p>bar</p>
```

Same with a `div` inside your outer `p`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at those styles (if you've shown us everything, that is), you seem to miss the `_grid` "element".

Try the following adjustment:

```
.works
  &__content_grid
    p > img
      width: 100px
```

Or, simply get rid of the `p` tag from the style, since `works__content` is actually its own class rather than its children's.

```css
.works
  &__content
    > img
      width: 100px
```

Comment: tried this still wont work, even changing the <p v-html></p> to <div v-html></div> still wont change the width

Comment: @carljustineoyales Can you make a fiddle for that so we can test?

Answer (score 0):

You should add `>>>` before the img tag.

```html
<style lang='sass' scoped>
.works
  &__content
   p
   >>> img // <-- Here
     width: 100px
</style>
```