# Django interprets safe filter weirdly

Tags: python, django, django-templates

We have a django template however I have a strange problem with data that is a rich-text.

Example:

template: `<p class="correctClass">{{team.description|safe}}</p>`

source code for `team.description` in our CMS: `<p>Correct text</p>`

result:

```
<p class="correctClass"></p>
<p>Correct text</p>
<p></p>
```

without safe filter it's like that:

```
<p class="correctClass">
    <p>Correct text</p> (this line is text, not parsed as html)
</p>
```

Of course wanted output is:

```
<p class="correctClass">Correct text</p>
```

Comment: try making the outter one a div ... maybe you cannot nest <p> (just a guess)

Comment: What is weird about that? You pass in a string having HTML, specify to Django that it is safe. Of course Django will render it like that. Do you want to strip all HTML tags in that string?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat why does it render what I gave in template code to first result code?
<parenttag>{{child|safe}}</parenttag> renders <parenttag></parenttag>(childContentGoesHere). How does it make any sense? :o

Comment: @JoranBeasley Lol it worked, but why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML tags inside paragraph <p>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35253694/html-tags-inside-paragraph-p)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to achieve that you can use the `striptags`.

```
<p class="correctClass">{{team.description|striptags}}</p>
```

"**Note that striptags doesn’t give any guarantee about its output being HTML safe, particularly with non valid HTML input. So NEVER apply the safe filter to a striptags output. If you are looking for something more robust, you can use the bleach Python library, notably its clean method.**" From the official documentation 
for more informations refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#striptags